# Upgrading maven 2 to maven 3

Tags: maven

when I upgrading maven I have problem with properties plugin:

```
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
```

in my pom I have defined properties:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.10-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>...</name>   



<properties>

    <!-- application -->
    <appname>appname1</appname>

</properties>

<build>
   ... // here I dont have properties plugin because I dont need them
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>${appname}</warName> // here is stil name in pom
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
...
</build>

<profiles>      

    <profile>
        <id>config</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>config</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <config>${basedir}/../config/${config}/build.properties</config>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <plugins>                   
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>initialize</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <files>
                                    <file>${config}</file>
                                </files>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>                    
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>

</profiles>

<dependencies>
...
</dependencies>

</project>
```

then I have profile:

```
<profile>
            <id>config</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>config</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <konfig>${basedir}/../config/${config}/build.properties</konfig>
            </properties>
            <build>
                <plugins>                    
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>initialize</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <files>
                                        <file>${konfig}</file>
                                    </files>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>                    
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
```

where I can specify another file with properties:

file contains:

```
 appname=appname2
```

so the logis is when I run mvn ... without profile properties are taken from pom. If use profile it should use properties in config file. This works with maven 2 but maven 3 still take properties from pom. Is there a way how to fix it ?

here: http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/read-project-properties-mojo.html  is written that:

Attributes:

```
Requires a Maven 2.0 project to be executed.
```

it means that this plugin is not supported with maven 3 ?

Comment: Can you show the complete pom, cause i doubt that this is based on the properties-maven-plugin.

Comment: I cant show whole pom but I edit it and show just important part. Interesting it that when I remove properties from pom then it works so there is just problem with rewriting properties

Comment: I have checked that with maven 3.0.3 which works perfectly. Can you post the pom file...

Comment: I am using 3.0.4. I just post pom. You didnt see it ?

Comment: What kind of properties do you want to set view the build.properties?

Comment: in build.properties I want to rewrite all properties which I have defined in pom.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When moving from Maven 2 to Maven 3 be careful because Maven 2 loads all dependencies at start-up and Maven 3 loads them on-demand.  So builds that work in Maven 3 will break on build boxes running Maven 2.  Lesson learned.